# Can't select all data in mysql databse with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database and a table in it called 'data'. There are 2 rows in this table.
I want to select all the data in there with php. Here is the code:

```
$FoodNamedata = mysqli_query($vb,"select * from data");
$FoodName = mysqli_fetch_array($FoodNamedata, MYSQL_NUM);
print_r($FoodName);
```

With this code it only selects the first ID in the table and prints it.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` returns one row, you need to put it in a loop like `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array(...))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$FoodNamedata = mysqli_query($vb,"select * from data");

while (($FoodName = mysqli_fetch_array($FoodNamedata, MYSQL_NUM))!==null) {
  print_r($FoodName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use it in a loop, if you want a single function here is some I made now:

```
<?php
  function get_data($link,$query) {
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $return = array();
    while($rec = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_NUM)) {
      $return[] = $rec;
    }
    return $return;
  }
?>
```

Then you just use

```
$foodname = get_data($vb,"select * from data");
```